# SSL handshake aborted - what is the exact reason?

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

While trying to establish a HTTPS connection, I get back an IOException:

```
SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x519ea2d8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

I guess it has something to do with an incomplete keychain - but how can I find out what the exact reason is for this error?

Answer (score 1):

> Connection reset by peer

This means that the server has closed the connection because it did not like what you have send to it. There are too few details to find out what really is going on but it might be the wrong protocol version, wrong ciphers etc in which case you might find more information on the server side. But it might also be a firewall in between cutting the connection because it violates the firewall policy.
If you have another client which can successfully connect make a packet capture of both and compare.

Comment: Wouldn't a server that is being under powered or being ddos-ed act the same way? That wouldn't mean we as a client did something wrong, wouldn't it? I'm working with a server that even responds with 404 at times even, the next second is back. Just curious were you take that into from

Comment: @CaptainCrunch: There are definitely similarities which can result in similar behavior. In general this kind of error without more context is not sufficient to determine what caused the problem and if the problem is the client, server or even something in between.