# Volley SSL Exception during registration into onilne mysql database form android app

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley

I have tried a lot of codes and techniques. But i could not find any solution. I also posted my problem on stackover flow but could not get any response. Thats why i am again posting this question.
I am new to android. I have a website which in now running online with secure SSL certificate. I have designed an android app where people will perform their registration. I want to save all their data into online mysql database of my website. I am using VOLLEY LIBRARY. When i click on register button from my android app, it is showing me this error:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x77754ed0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer.
```

Please Help me. I am begginer to android. I cant solve this problem.
This is my Main Activity.java Code:

```
package com.myapper.hasee.server;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Creating EditText.
    EditText FirstName, LastName, Email ;

    // Creating button;
    Button InsertButton;

    // Creating Volley RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    // Create string variable to hold the EditText Value.
    String FirstNameHolder, LastNameHolder, EmailHolder ;

    // Creating Progress dialog.
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // Storing server url into String variable.
    String HttpUrl = "https://bomvibe.com/folder_name/myfile.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Assigning ID's to EditText.
        FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
        LastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        // Assigning ID's to Button.
        InsertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonInsert);

        // Creating Volley newRequestQueue .
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Adding click listener to button.
        InsertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Showing progress dialog at user registration time.
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait, We are Inserting Your Data on Server");
                progressDialog.show();

                // Calling method to get value from EditText.
                GetValueFromEditText();

                // Creating string request with post method.
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                                // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                                progressDialog.dismiss();

                                // Showing response message coming from server.
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                                // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                                progressDialog.dismiss();

                                // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                        // Creating Map String Params.
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // Adding All values to Params.
                        params.put("first_name", FirstNameHolder);
                        params.put("last_name", LastNameHolder);
                        params.put("email", EmailHolder);

                        return params;
                    }

                };

                // Creating RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

                // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }
        });

    }

    // Creating method to get value from EditText.
    public void GetValueFromEditText(){

        FirstNameHolder = FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
        LastNameHolder = LastName.getText().toString().trim();
        EmailHolder = Email.getText().toString().trim();

    }

}
```

Hope i will get a good solution at this time. Thanks in advance experts:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34484223/3996989

Comment: @SabaJafarzadeh what will be its solution??

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984295/android-pre-lollipop-devices-giving-error-ssl-handshake-aborted-ssl-0x618d9c18